# Screen flickering after debian upgrade to sid

Tags: linux, debian

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad E540 and just upgraded to Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid

Now when I start up my laptop and get the login page, the screen starts flickering quite heavily. After login in to xfce or cinnamon, the problem still persists and it's almost impossible to look at the screen for more than 30 seconds due to the constant brightness changes.

I have an external screen attached to the laptop and it's just fine, so I thought it might be some hardware problem, so I restarted into windows (I have dual boot) but I don't have any problem there.

So i believe this problem was caused by the upgrade.

Here is a link to `dmesg` output:
http://pastebin.com/1ep4gu5R

```
lspci | grep -e VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

I do not have a `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11/` but this has not given me a problem in the past

I don't know what other information would be of use. Let me know and I'll post it right away.

Does anyone have idea how to fix this?

====== Update =====

Some extra info

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at f1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 6000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GK208M [GeForce GT 740M]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at <ignored> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nouveau
```

It seems that this issue affects multiple people, as seen in: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=128702

I followed the steps there and removed `xserver-xorg-video-inte`  with `--purge` but that didn't help.

> There is a chance that the flickering could be due to PWM problems
>   with your monitor

I noticed i have an intel i915, it seems i might be having this issue:

> Backlight PWM modulation frequency (Intel i915 only)

I tried the commands stated there, then i checked the calculator (link in website above) and i tried with different Hz, from 1 to 5000. I did see them doing some changed on the screen, but non fixed the problem...

```
sudo intel_reg write 0xC8254 0x13131313
sudo intel_reg write 0xC8254 0x3f943f94
sudo intel_reg write 0xC8254 0xc300c3
sudo intel_reg write 0xC8254 0xee6c1e6b3
sudo intel_reg write 0xC8254 0x7a107a1
```

So, still no fix. Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen somewhere that it might be an issue with the i915 power saving mode.
The file /sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_psr was set to 1 which mean that saving mode was enabled.

To test it, i switched off power saving:

```
echo "0" > /sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_psr
```

And to "activate" the new settings, i ran in the shell glxgears, and i could see that the flickering was almost gone. But after closing glxgears panel the flickering started again.

To make this permanent, i changed /etc/default/grub and added the fix to make it permanent:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_psr=0"
```

After this i rebooted and the flickering was almost gone. There is still some but i can deal with it, i barely notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Debian Stretch, using Gnome. The fix was thankfully simple:

`"Settings" --> "Power" --> "Automatic Brightness" = "Off"`